# Can we only use keras model with low loss in its epoch without saving the model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a neural network model built using TF Keras and I am running for n epochs. But is it possible to choose the model which has low loss during its epoch run without saving the model in the first place ? I know there exists callbacks, which saves the best weight of the model. But do we have any other method without saving?

Thank you in advance